# Can't generate faker image in Laravel

Tags: php, html, image, laravel-8, faker

I have a problem with my code. I try to generate a faker image in Laravel 8, but it's not showing like the image in my path.

**PostFactory**

```
class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence(mt_rand(2, 8)),
            'slug' => $this->faker->slug(),
            'excerpt' => $this->faker->paragraph(),
            'image' => $this->faker
                ->image('public/img/posts', 640, 480, null, false),
            'body' => $this->faker->paragraph(mt_rand(5, 10)),
            'user_id' => mt_rand(1, 3),
            'category_id' => mt_rand(1, 2)
        ];
    }
}
```

**Blade/View**

```
 <img width="600" class="rounded" src="/img/posts/{{ $post->image }}" 
     alt="/img/posts/{{ $post->image }}">
```

Comment: Make sure the image is saved in the directory you want after executing the factory

Comment: @MrEduar yeah we've to do that but still incorrect image like in my directory

Comment: make sure that you have /img/ folder under public..

Answer (score 2):

The solution that I have found so far is to modify your image file inside vendor in the path vendor\fakerphp\faker\src\Faker\Provider\Image.php
adding the lines that I have below since the creator of via is giving problems in receiving the data via url, to which we can always use the method either imageUrl or simply the image method I leave you my modification below

```
public const BASE_URL = 'https://placehold.jp'; // change the url

Once this file is opened, we will search the lines approx 114 and add the following code, let's take the existing code as a reference

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); //existing line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);//new line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//new line
$success = curl_exec($ch) && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200;//existing line
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this package. it work well since it is using GD extension to generate image not curl.

[Faker-Bilions-Images](https://github.com/bilions-org/faker-bilions-images)

```
$faker->addProvider(new FakerImageProvider($faker));
$image = $faker->image(null, 640, 480);
$filePath = Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs('seeder-images', new File($image), basename($image));
```

Answer (score -2):

I think I tried to solve this in this post regarding the issue of the image generated by faker, I hope I can help you in something

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73059602/16158744

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).